# Using ARcore in vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

Has anyone tried using ARcore capabilities in vuforia?
The instructions for enabling ARcore in vuforia are given in this link [Arcore in vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/arcore-with-vuforia.html) . Has anyone followed this instructions and tested whether it works?

**After I followed the above steps I had no way of confirming whether ARCore is being used by the app.**

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but not using ARCore. Quote from the page you have linked:

> If the Android device does not support ARCore or the application is not configured properly, then Vuforia Engine will use its own plane-finding technology.

Comment: Yes my main question was if anyone tried using ARcore in Vuforia and whether it works properly

Comment: @Kitwradr No, you had two questions, the first one is unnecessary, and JackMini36 answered your second: "If we use like this do the apps work on phones which do not have support for ARCore?"

Comment: Uneecessary? That is my main question. Whether someone has used ARcore in Vuforia.

Comment: @Kitwradr Yes, Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Otherwise I can give you an answer: `No`